# Why this pig latin word conversion code is not working

Tags: c

Pig Latin Word conversion

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100],pg[100];
    int len,i,j,k;
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",s);
    len=strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]>=65&&s[i]<=90)
        {
            s[i]=s[i]+32;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='a'|| s[i]=='e'||s[i]=='i'||s[i]=='o'||s[i]=='u')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    pg[len]='a';
    pg[len+1]='y';
    for(j=0;j<len-i;j++)
    {
        pg[j]=s[i+j];
    }
    for(k=0;k<i;k++)
    {
        pg[j+k]=s[k];
    }
    printf("Pig Latin word is: %s",pg);
}
```

I checked if at any step the letters are not the desired ones which are assigned. But no. By instead of using the line

```
printf("Pig Latin word is: %s",pg);
```

if i use

```
for(i=0;i<len+2;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",pg[i]);
    }
```

it is showing correctly. Why

Comment: *Aside*: `"%[^\n]s"` is a "beginner's hybrid". The `%[]` format specifier is not a subset of the `%s` specifier. Typically you should use either `"%99s"` or `"%99[^\n]"` if you want it to include spaces. They are different specifiers.

Comment: Are you properly null-terminating your strings?

Comment: Means ? And how is it affecting the code ?

Comment: [read up on C strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strings-in-c-2/)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but this should be avoided: `s[i]>=65&&s[i]<=90`. If you man `'A'` write `'A'` instead of some magic number. You should also take a look at `toupper` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me as-is but that might be luck.  You still need to zero terminate your string since an array declared as a local variable is not necessarily initialized to zero.  Try adding:

```
pg[len + 2] = '\0';
```

Unrelated, but consider also including a newline in your printf format string:

```
printf("Pig Latin word is: %s\n", pg);
```

Your code will also break if you give it a string like

```
this string is over 100 characters long this string is over 100 characters long this string is over 100 characters long
```

You need to make sure you're doing the proper bounds checking.

Comment: Yeah after adding `printf("Pig Latin word is: %s\n", pg);` it is working properly